# No resource group in IBM Cloud lite account

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage

so I have a lite account. I was trying to create an object storage when I saw that I don't have any resource group. I went into Manage -> Account -> Resource groups and it's empty. I tried to create one but it wouldn't let me without upgrading.

I created an account after enrolling in the IBM Full Stack Developer course in Coursera. I tried to create another account with the same Feature Code but it's not working.

Please help

I tried talking to the AI chat support. It told me to go into IAM -> users -> Assign access but it's saying this - "Looks like you don't have access to create policies for IAM-enabled services, Account management services, or Cloud Foundry. Contact the account owner for access."

Comment: AFAIK there are no "lite" accounts, only trial accounts. Could you check here and confirm your type of account? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-accounts#compare

Comment: Yes my bad, it's the trial account.

Answer (score 0):

Check your personal user IAM access permissions.  Maybe you do not have permissions to list resource groups.  In the top middle see Manage > Acccess (IAM).  Click Users.  Click self. Click access and verify you are in the Admin group.

Comment: Hi, I checked and it seems I'm not in the admin group. What can I do?